# Xamarin No Resource found that matches the given name @integer/google_play_services_version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to develop an app where you can send push notifications to the users with firebase cloud messaging.

I literally tried everything that i could find on the internet, but I doesn't seem to fix the problem. I compile using android 7.0 Nougat.

I already have this in my manifest file:

meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"

When I import google play services to my project, and build, this error appears.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').  firebaseTest    C:\Users\andre\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\firebaseTest\firebaseTest\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml 14

This problem is really driving me crazy, and I would love if someone could help me solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you already get a chance to looking into doing it via azure?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm

I havent tried going direct to firebase but if you wanted to send messages via google messaging this is what I'd recommend.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitly look into this!